# Fullscreen mode - Windows 10 App (JS)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, fullscreen, windows-10, uwp, windows

**Hello**,
i searched around the web, and can't found a right code or something, to run my app as Fullscreen. I want to make that, active a fullscreen mode and auto-hide the title bar(with buttons). I'm a beginner with Visual Studios and Windows 10 app develop. I'm trying to create a JS app.

I can found only for C#/C++ app's a fullscreen mode, but can't find for JS.

https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/FullScreenTitleBarRepo/tree/master/FullScreenTitleBarRepo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an official [Full screen mode sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FullScreenMode), there is a js project in this sample.

If you want to launch the app as fullscreen, you can use the [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode.aspx) and [ApplicationViewWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewwindowingmode.aspx) in the `default.js` like this:

```js
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
    "use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

var ViewManagement = Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
var ApplicationViewWindowingMode = ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode;
var ApplicationView = ViewManagement.ApplicationView;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application was suspended and then terminated.
            // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
        }           
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.fullScreen;
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state that needs to persist across suspensions here.
    // You might use the WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically saved and restored across suspension.
    // If you need to complete an asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call args.setPromise().
};

app.start();

})();
```